# What do the parameters(ie. radius) mean in Folium heatmap and markercluster?

Tags: python, heatmap, markerclusterer, folium

I am new to folium,

```
1. when I plotted the heatmap, there are parameters radius and and 
max_val that I would like to know the meaning behind? Is there a 
unit for the radius? How to explain the algorithm of heatmap?


2.How are folium markercluster positions based on?
```

Any help will be appreciated a lot.

Answer (score 0):

The unit of radius parameter is pixel.
And the default radius of markercluster library is 80.